# How to use Google Fonts API in React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, google-fonts

I am trying to set Google Fonts in my React project but I am not being able to override the original font families of React.

Following some tutorials I inserted the font-family I want into `index.css`:

```
body {
  /* margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Lemonada'
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; */
  font-family: 'Lemonada', 
    cursive;
}
```

I commented the original fonts for testing purposes.

However the original fonts are not being overwritten:

[image]

If I inspect the file I see this:

[image]

As you can see all the commented fonts are still there, besides there are a lot of other things that doesn't exist in `index.css`. Apparently it is coming from some `style.css` file, but I have no idea where to find this.

If I uncheck this style I get the font-family I want:

[image]
[image]

And of course, I also added the api to my `index.html` file.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemonada:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

I'd like to be able to add new font-families or at least override the original ones.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept digging and I found two possible solutions:

`1-` Instead of using the `index.css`, I put the font-family direct inside the css file corresponding to the component I want to use the font, in this case this is the file `Layout.css`.

`2-` I found out this library and it also works and seems to be very great: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-font-loader

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lemonada:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">` is loaded before the  of your css file.

Also try changing the line to

```
  font-family: 'Lemonada' !important,
```